# tikz draw connects labels not nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to connect nodes but my code connects labels not node.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\nx{5}
\def\ny{5}
\foreach \i in {0, ..., \nx}{
    \fill (0:11-\i) ++ (70:\i) ++ (110:\i) circle (2pt) node[right] (f\i) {$f_\i$};
}
\foreach \j in {0, ..., \ny}{
    \fill (0:\j) ++ (70:\j) ++ (110:\j) circle (2pt) node[left] (e\j) {$e_\j$};
}
\draw (f0) -- (f5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

gives

[image]

I want to connect the filled dots f0 and f5. Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: Please make your given code snippet be compilable ...

Comment: Write `coordinate (f\i)` and `coordinate (e\j)` before `circle` to name the coordinate and not the node (remove the naming there, of course).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you! Can I add the name though? I need to name each node by f1, f2, ...f5, and e1, ..., e5.

Comment: @whwjddnjs Keep the node, just remove the naming of it (the part between parentheses), or name it differently than your coordinates. E.g. `\fill (0:11-\i) ++ (70:\i) ++ (110:\i) coordinate (f\i) circle (2pt) node[right] {$f_\i$};`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you! It works!

Answer (score 2):

Try to draw nodes instead circles and nodes with text insert as labels to this nodes:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.append style = {circle, fill, inner sep=2pt,
                     label=#1}
                     ]
\def\nx{5}
\def\ny{5}
\foreach \i in {0, ..., \nx}
{
    \path (0:11-\i) ++ (70:\i) ++ (110:\i) node (f\i) [dot=right:$f_\i$] {};
}
\foreach \j in {0, ..., \ny}
{
    \path (0:\j)   ++ (70:\j) ++ (110:\j) node (e\j) [dot=left:$e_\j$] {};
}
\draw (f0) -- (f5);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]